# Thread-safe Singleton class

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, singleton

in my project i am trying to use singleton class to store data in it. When im trying to access it from Service class, its creating new instance instead of using previous Singleton instance. I read a lot of post on github and couldn't find working answer

My Singleton class

```
import android.util.Log;
import com.softelnet.ksavi.android.model.AttachmentRequest;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AttachmentsUpdateQueue {


    private static class Holder {
        private static final AttachmentsUpdateQueue singleInstance = new AttachmentsUpdateQueue();
    }


    private AttachmentsUpdateQueue() {
        Log.d("pox", "new instance");
    }

    private LinkedList<AttachmentRequest> attachmentsQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    public static AttachmentsUpdateQueue getInstance() {
        return Holder.singleInstance;

    }

    public AttachmentRequest getAttachmentForUpload() {
        Log.d("pox", "get, size:" + attachmentsQueue.size());
        if (attachmentsQueue.size() > 0) {
            return attachmentsQueue.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }

    public int getSize() {
        return attachmentsQueue.size();
    }

    public void addAttachmentForUpload(AttachmentRequest attachment) {
        attachmentsQueue.addLast(attachment);
        Log.d("pox", "added, size:" + attachmentsQueue.size());
    }
}
```

Adding data to Singleton

```
AttachmentsUpdateQueue.getInstance().addAttachmentForUpload(new AttachmentRequest(oprCtx.getUser(),task.getId(),attachment,isAttribute));
```

Getting data from Singleton

```
 AttachmentRequest req = AttachmentsUpdateQueue.getInstance().getAttachmentForUpload();
```

Comment: Where is it creating a new instance?

Comment: The best way to create a Singleton is to use Java Enums. Here's a quick read: https://www.baeldung.com/java-singleton

Comment: when im trying to access Singleton in Service class. The first attempt ends with creating a new instance

Comment: Why are you asking some "holder" class for a Singleton instead of asking the Singleton itself?

Comment: @hfontanez , beacouse im trying to code it in every way, hope i ll find one that will works

Comment: @JakubSroka then simply create the singleton and ask it for a reference of itself. That's how the Singleton Design Pattern works. No need to morph it into something else.

Comment: Ignore @hfontanez advice - it's dubious at best. `enum` doesn't exactly scream "singleton!", after all. The 'holder' solution as OP is employing here is totally fine. If that log line is printing more than once, something else is going wrong, and e.g. 'use an enum!' is not going to fix this. re-classloading or android specific shenanigans perhaps.

Comment: @hfontanez this 'holder' thing __is__ the singleton pattern. OP is not asking for the holder, they're asking for the singleton. Which is in the holder, but the holder is an implementation detail.

Comment: This thread is a bit funny; lots of folks falling all over themselves trying to explain what's wrong with your code. __There is nothing wrong with your code__, that is an industry standard singleton. The problem is presumably android-specific: It is unloading your app in between calls. Trivial proof: Run that code in a standard JVM to see that the constructor is only ever invoked precisely once.

Comment: @rzwitserloot dubious? LOL.... Alright, I guess Joshua Bloch and the rest of the Java architects got it wrong. I see. I'll make sure they get your memo.

Comment: The holder pattern is a bit more recent. The enum 'trick' is not bad, just, not quite as good as the holder solution. Answering a question with "Hey, instead of 'this totally fine thing', why not use 'this equivalent alternative instead'" - wastes OP's time.

Comment: @hfontanez I used a singleton before, and everything was fine, but when I try to use it in Service it creating another instance. its a bit weried, and making me mad

Answer (score 0):

may be you can write like this, which is named DCL(double check lock).

```
private volatile static AttachmentsUpdateQueue instance = null;
private AttachmentsUpdateQueue(){
    System.out.println("Single: " + System.nanoTime());
}

public static AttachmentsUpdateQueue getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        synchronized (AttachmentsUpdateQueue.class) {
            if(instance == null){
                singleInstance = new AttachmentsUpdateQueue();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Just use an enum....

Comment: its not working :/

Comment: D/pox: Single: 19904804726440
D/pox: przed 434745232D/pox: added, size:1
D/pox: Single: 19918035672210
D/pox: get, size:0
D/pox: its null
D/pox: upload attachment

Comment: This is just incorrect. THe singleton holder pattern as OP is using is superior to this in every way.

Comment: why not work ? should be ok war, I also used in my project.
if so , enum is also a good way .

   
 public enum Singleton {

    INSTANCE;

    public void getInstance() {
        System.out.println("doSomething");
    }